# TextInputLayout enabled not saved after destroy and recreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-textinputlayout, android-savedstate

Simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.infinitebounds.myapplication.Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I am disabling the `textInputLayout` if the activity is initialised for the first time:

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var tip: TextInputLayout
    lateinit var et: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        tip = findViewById(R.id.tip) as TextInputLayout
        et = findViewById(R.id.et) as EditText

        if (savedInstanceState == null) tip.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

I have checked "Don't Keep Activities" option.

So initially when the activity is launched, the `TextInputLayout` is disabled. When I press home and come back, it is re-enabled again.

So my questions are:

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. How do I keep `TextInputLayout` disabled when recreated?

**Edit:**

This seems to happen with the `EditText` as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the expected behaviour?

Yes, it is (assuming *"Don't Keep Activities"* is checked).

First time the app is being launched the `savedInstanceState` is null - your `if` check passes and sets `TextInputLayout`'s state to disabled.

As soon as you press home button and come back, `onCreate()` is being called, but this time `savedInstanceState` is **not** null - your `if` check does **not** pass.

> How do I keep TextInputLayout disabled when recreated?

Get rid of of `if` check entirely, it's useless. Perform `tip.isEnabled = false` directly within `onCreate()`, or perform that in `xml`: `android:enabled="false"`.

Comment: So the "enabled" state of a widget is not saved, like how an `EditText`'s text is for example?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `state is not saved`?  See whether [`android:saveEnabled="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:saveEnabled) fulfil your needs.

Comment: I mean for example, when an `EditText` has some text and has an unique id, that text is saved(by Android) when its `Activity` is recreated and as a result it contains the text. I was wondering if this was the case for `isEnabled` as well. Apparently not, i'll have to set it explicitly every time it is recreated.

Comment: Apply `android:saveEnabled="false"` to both `TextInputLayout` and to `EditText`: the state won't be saved by Android.